# Are iPhone DCIM 1xxAPPLE folders chronological?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

For example, am I guaranteed once 100APPLE is full, it will never change?

I am manually backing up the folders and this would make my life easier. Also when moving to a new iPhone, it means I can continue to only back up the new folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don’t think you can count on that being guaranteed.

Yes, chronological filling first is typical and unless someone messes with the storage or counters / settings you’re pretty save with that assumption/generalization.

For my sanity, I grab all the images and process later if I feel I can’t just store all the images from each device. So far, my main storage grows faster than the size and accumulated count of images since iPhone launch 10 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Nobody is messing with the folders / counters, so I'm just going to assume chronological. I don't have enough storage to keep grabbing them all, I just want the new ones. This is especially true after a phone upgrade.